# Introduce incremental run number in sql based on another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, increment, cumulative-sum

I am trying to replicate below table, last column "Run number" is the desired output. Based on run flag column, this run number increments (at 1) or maintains (at 0) its value as shown.

Based on similar questions on this site and google, I tested Row_number function but I can't find right column to decide partitions.
[image]

Comment: pls see sample data attached, in original post somehow attach was not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function `sum() over()`

```
...
RunNumber = sum([Run Start Flag]) over ( order by [Product Created Date])
...
```

Comment: Thanks, so quick. This looks pretty obvious that should work, but syntax error near 'order'.

Comment: @user7256821 syntax looks correct given the column names

Comment: I use SQL server 2008 and I find that perhaps order by clause does not work in aggregated window function, such as sum over(). Please advise.